# Not finished walls in electrical room

Tags: electrical-panel, drain-waste-vent

The electrical room in the basement of the condo building I live (3 floors + basement, top floor has a mezzanine, 8 units total, in Montreal, Canada) has walls not finished. See photos.

There are gaps in the corners that weren't finished, so basically free air flows into the walls. I wonder if this has a function, or it was just laziness from the builder to save time.

**Are these openings something that we can fill with silicone and be done with? Any recommendations on how to proceed?**

More information:

My concern with these gaps is that due chimney effect the air flows to my unit (top floor). I have to keep on top of other units so they periodically fill the P traps that dry (especially the emergency one, next to the hot water tank, that one is never used). BTW: I do not discard that there is a crack in the vent system, but again, the smell goes up, from within the walls. I already got two different companies checking for mold, and a plumber who wants to do a smoke test, but the condo association just doesn't smell anything (according to them). So I am left with no options.

I'd like to minimize the flow of air.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @GregNickoloff Whether the gaps can simply be filled with the first product that comes to mind, or whether particular products should be used, or whether they should not be filled at all.

Comment: They could make you take it all out if you do not get approval.

Comment: @harper - yeah I guess so. There was a bunch of other stuff about water heaters and smoke tests and so on....

Comment: @GregNickoloff: as Harper explained, I am asking about what to about the gaps. I reformatted the question, hoping it is easier to understand. I am trying to provide the full picture. I have been dealing with this issue since ~5 months ago and nobody seems to really know or care.

Comment: @EdBeal: I understand that. First I want to know if the gaps exist for a reason or they could be filled with silicone or whatever other product. If they can be filled, I might push for it to be filled.

Comment: *"the smell goes up, from within the walls*"  How do you know that?  Do you smell the same smell in the utility room that you smell in your apt.??   If no one else smells it then stands to reason that the smell is in or near your unit.

Comment: Yes. I think that you *could* seal the gaps with silicone or something similar. I don't believe that the gaps were left intentionally. If the architect/builder, etc. would have wanted to vent the room they would have installed proper vents not "gaps"...but I don't think sealing the gaps is the answer to your problem.

Comment: It seems to me that the real problem is that you get a stink in your apartment and  just filling the gaps might keep the smell out, but it does nothing to fix the cause of the smell. It's like turning up the car radio to fix a broken exhaust system. I  don't really understand this remark either, *"...I have to keep on top of other units so they periodically fill the P traps..."* Which/what P-traps are involved and how do they relate to the gaps in the walls? What kind of P-traps are there in an electrical room?

Comment: There should not be any smell coming from a electrical room so I doubt that is the problem but there is no reason for the seams not being closed. In a multi occupancy building there is probably fire stop seals at each floor so sealing the cracks would be a waste of time and $. I would get some tracking smoke, we sometimes use it in HVAC ductwork to identify strange flow patterns, note it will set off many particulate smoke detectors. Pop a can in the room and see if it makes it to your apartment. I am also surprised that room is not locked but I do see a meter so that may be why.

Comment: First, thanks for everybody's feedback.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: it is the same smell in the corridors, the utility room and my apartment. It *seems* to be stronger as you go higher (in the corridor, and in my apartment). I know it comes from within the walls because I have removed the outlets faces and you feel the current and get the smell. I have also smell it IN the apartements in the basement. I believe I am more sensitive or more expose (or both) that everybody else and that's the reason I smell and they don't. I haven't been the only one smelling it, the plumber did, some friends have done it.

Comment: @GregNickoloff: I agree. Sealing that will not 100% fix the problem. As explained, I do not know what to do, where to get help. I even had the fire fighters coming (they didn't detected anything in the whole 10 minutes they spent here). I am trying to minimize the airflow, trying to get a lesser current of air moving.

Comment: @GregNickoloff: about the P-trap remark. 1) there is one floor drain in every apartment next to the water heater tank. That drain never gets water, so you have to fill it in periodically. People don't do it. Since they don't feel the smell, they forget. So I have to go knock on their door every 2 months and ask "Did you put water in your drain?".  The dried-out P-trap would leave smelly gas into the building, which I believe chimney effect is bringing to me. There is a floor drain in the electrical room - I am not sure if there is a P-trap there (I put water anyways).

Comment: @GregNickoloff: about me not addressing the real issue (the smell): 100% agree. I just don't know who else to get involved. The condo association doesn't want to do anything, the city won't do anything. The condo doesn't let me run a smoke test (even if I pay for it). So, I am hoping to keep the smell out and maybe increasing the level in the corridor so they notice and act.

Comment: @EdBeal: thanks for the suggestion. I have a key to the room. The smell might be coming from 1) the floor drain that is IN the room, 2) the apartments next to it, 3) a broken pipe *below* the floor. Note: a few times I have got positive readings everywhere in the building with a combustible gas detector (ET120 Klein Tools, https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/combustion-gas-leak-detectors/combustible-gas-leak-detector). I had it replaced by the manufactured just in case, and I am waiting the right opportunity to test again.

Comment: Everybody: my main hypothesis is that the drain vent is perforated, cracked, broken somewhere within the walls. Without the smoke test that's going to be hard to find and resolve. I am just trying to mitigate.

Comment: I see. I don't think this is as much a "home improvement" issue as perhaps a legal issue then. If the building is filling up with sewer gas I'd think that's a public health problem that the building owner needs to address.

Comment: @GregNickoloff: it is a condo building. I own my unit. If I was just able to scientifically prove there is a public health issue I could treat with lawyers. I haven't found a service/contractor capable of doing so. At it is: it is just my nose against the others.

Comment: @rufo many years back I learned a trick that helps to seal unused floor drains without plugging them. A cup of cooking oil in the drain works wonders it doesn’t evaporate and as long as there is not a high flow situation it will last years. The oil traps the water on the house side and on the plumbing side the humidity is high so it doesn’t evaporate. I learned this when I had a basement that we had a dehumidifier in that caused the trap to need filling regularly. After adding the cooking oil I never had to add water again but I only lived there ~2 years after that.  I would give oil a try.

Comment: Nice tip, @EdBeal!

Comment: @GregNickoloff I found something interesting related to this issue. I opened a new question, maybe you can help me out. Thank you VERY much. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176518/backwater-valve-access-sleeve-cap-broken-sewer-gas-smell

Comment: @EdBeal  I found something interesting related to this issue. I opened a new question, maybe you can help me out. Thank you VERY much https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176518/backwater-valve-access-sleeve-cap-broken-sewer-gas-smell

Comment: @AlaskaMan I found something interesting related to this issue. I opened a new question, maybe you can help me out. Thank you VERY much https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176518/backwater-valve-access-sleeve-cap-broken-sewer-gas-smell

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the gaps are a “Fire Code” issue, ( in the U.S., anyway...I don’t know about Canada, but I suspect it’s similar.)

You indicate your building is 3 stories plus a basement. In the U.S., this requires “Fire Resistant” construction, unless there are automatic fire sprinklers throughout the building.

What this means is that gypsum board must be on each side of each wall to protect the structural framework of the building. They call this a “1-hour Fire rating”. Without this gypsum board covering the building is “non-rated construction” and the building is limited to 2 stories.

Gaps in the gypsum board covering is of utmost concern in the electrical room where a fire is of extreme importance.

I would notify my HOA or building management services of this concern. If they do not take action, I’d notify your local Building Official of your concern.

I doubt the gaps are creating a smell into your unit. There may be a broken sewerline in the wall that allows a smell to seep into your unit. If you cal “rattle” pipes, that would be an indication that pipes are loose, broken, etc.

Another option to your smell situation could be that a vent below you is tied into your sewerline allowing the smell to seep into your unit through the plumbing vents. You’ll need access to the lower units and a smart plumber to figure that one out.